# Python tcp connection get data script

Tags: python, sockets

I have a remote device which sends text data on TCP 5005 port.  The code below is to get the data from remote device but its throwing an error.  Can someone please help on this.

```
conn, addr = s.accept()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\socket.py", line 197, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
socket.error: [Errno 10022] An invalid argument was supplied"
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = '192.168.0.12'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))


conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print "received data:", data
    conn.send(data)  # echo
conn.close()
```

Comment: `accept`s listening socket, so instead of `connect`ing to some socket, you must do `s.bind((HOST, PORT))` then `s.listen(10)`.

Comment: the IP 192.168.0.12 is remote system IP can I use bind here

Comment: It seems now your device is listening for connection then. If it is so, the you do `connect` and then `recv` on your socket (without any call to `accept`).

Comment: ok I have changed code. Please see below code. When I run the code it did not respond after.I am not able to get data.             #!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = '192.168.0.12'
TCP_PORT = 5005

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.recv(1024)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    print "received data:", data
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
print "received data:", data
conn.close()

Comment: Please update your question

Comment: I repeat, if you connect to socket, you do not call `accept` at all 'cause this is what listening socket does.